# Finding 3rd, or any other highest area value of image segment in matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, image-segmentation

I am writing the code according to this https://in.mathworks.com/help/images/correcting-nonuniform-illumination.html

basically after my step of doing say

```
grain_areas = [graindata.Area]
[area, id] = max(grain_areas)
```

from these lines i will get the segment of the image which has the highest area, however i want the segment which has say in this case the 3rd highest area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `sort` with the `'descend'` options to get the areas from largest to smallest. Then you can access the *nth* largest area as you please

```
grain_areas_sorted = sort(grain_areas, 'descend');
grain_areas_sorted(3)

ans =

   236
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using MATLAB 2017b or newer, you can just use the function `maxk` which will give you the kth largest number.

```
[area, id] = maxk(grain_areas,3);
```